# Translations between screen co-ordinates and image co-ordinates after scaling and zooming

Tags: java, translation, scaling, zooming

I have a class that manages translating from screen co-ordinates to image co-ordinates.
However, I have an "off by one error".

The following gives 318, 198, instead of 319, 199:

```
@Test
public void test6rightScreenCornerToImageCoOrdAfterZoomingAndScaling() {
    PointTranslation pointTranslation = new PointTranslation();
    pointTranslation.setOriginalSize(0, 0, 320, 200); // original image
    pointTranslation.zoomIn(9, 9, 310, 190); // zoomed image starting at 9,9
    pointTranslation.scale(0, 0, 800, 800);

    Point translatedPoint = pointTranslation.transformPoint(799,799);
    System.out.println(testName.getMethodName() + " : " + translatedPoint.toString());
    assertTrue(translatedPoint.x == 319);
    assertTrue(translatedPoint.y == 199);
}
```

=============================================================

Full Listing:

```
package gtx;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.gdip.PointF;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.gdip.RectF;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class PointTranslation {
RectF originalSize = null;
RectF currentSize = null;
RectF scaledSize = null;

public void setOriginalSize(int originX, int originY, int width, int height) {
    originalSize = getRectangle(originX, originY, width, height);
    currentSize = originalSize;
}

public void zoomIn(int originX, int originY, int width, int height) {
    // System.out.println("addTranslation: " + originX + " " + originY + " "
    // + width + " " + height);
    currentSize = getRectangle(originX, originY, width, height);
}

public void scale(int originX, int originY, int width, int height) {
    // System.out.println("addTranslation: " + originX + " " + originY + " "
    // + width + " " + height);
    scaledSize = getRectangle(originX, originY, width, height);
}

public boolean isPointWithinBounds(Point point) {
    return isPointWithinBounds(point.x, point.y);
}

public boolean isPointWithinBounds(int xPos, int yPos) {
    boolean ret = false;

    if (scaledSize != null) {
        RectF sourceRec = scaledSize;
        int xBounds = (int) (sourceRec.Width + sourceRec.X);
        int yBounds = (int) (sourceRec.Height + sourceRec.Y);
        ret = (xPos < xBounds) && (yPos < yBounds) && (xPos > sourceRec.X) && (yPos > sourceRec.Y);
    }

    return ret;
}

public Point transformPoint(Point point) {
    return transformPoint(point.x, point.y);
}

public Point transformPoint(int xPos, int yPos) {
    Point sourcePoint = new Point((int) xPos, (int) yPos);
    Point retPoint = sourcePoint;

    if (this.scaledSize != null) {
        retPoint = transformPoint(this.scaledSize, this.currentSize, sourcePoint);
    }
    return retPoint;
}

/*
 * Rectangle 1 has (x1, y1) origin and (w1, h1) for width and height, and
 * Rectangle 2 has (x2, y2) origin and (w2, h2) for width and height, then
 * 
 * Given point (x, y) in terms of Rectangle 1 co-ords, to convert it to
 * Rectangle 2 co-ords: xNew = ((x-x1)/w1)*w2 + x2; yNew = ((y-y1)/h1)*h2 +
 * y2;
 */
private Point transformPoint(RectF source, RectF destination, Point intPoint) {
    PointF point = new PointF();
    point.X = intPoint.x;
    point.Y = intPoint.y;
    return transformPoint(source, destination, point);
}

private Point transformPoint(RectF source, RectF destination, PointF point) {
    return new Point((int) ((((point.X - source.X) / source.Width) * destination.Width + destination.X)),
            (int) ((((point.Y - source.Y) / source.Height) * destination.Height + destination.Y)));
}

private RectF getRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    RectF rect = new RectF();
    rect.X = x;
    rect.Y = y;
    rect.Height = height;
    rect.Width = width;
    return rect;
}

private PointF getPoint(int x, int y) {
    PointF retPoint = new PointF();
    retPoint.X = x;
    retPoint.Y = y;
    return retPoint;
}

public void reset() {
    this.originalSize = null;
    this.currentSize = null;
    this.scaledSize = null;
}
}
```

## Update:

My issue definitely seems to be with rounding.  Its strange, for some test cases I need to Round Up to get the correct Point, and sometimes I need to round Up.  I am missing something like a scaling factor or something.  Any suggestions how to the Translation between two Rectangles correctly?

## **Update 2:**

I tried the following method, but with still no joy:

```
    private Point transformPoint(RectF source, RectF destination, PointF point) {   
        float xPercent = normalize(point.X,source.X,source.Width);
        float destX = xPercent*(Math.abs(destination.Width - destination.X)) + destination.X;

        float yPercent = normalize(point.Y,source.Y,source.Height);
        float destY = yPercent*(Math.abs(destination.Height - destination.Y)) + destination.Y;

        System.out.println("Float x,y: " + destX + ", " + destY);
        System.out.println("Ceil Float x,y: " + Math.floor(destX) + ", " + Math.floor(destY) );

        return new Point((int)Math.floor(destX), (int)Math.floor(destY));
    }

    private float normalize(float value, float min, float max) {
        return Math.abs((value - min) / (max - min));
    }
```

Comment: In `test6` what point are you using?

Comment: @LorisSecuro - updated now - thanks

Comment: The code in your question is not complete. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Roman - OK, updated now

Comment: Your code is now missing PointTranslation.addTranslation method as referenced in your test case.  The code was there prior to your updates.

Comment: @ReenactorRob - updated now

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy If the top left pixel is (0,0), then the bottom right pixel is (319, 199) and the pixel (320, 200) doesn't exist. It make sense that the result is (318, 198) since the `zoomIn` doesn't reach the bottom right corner but it stops 1 pixel before.

Answer (score 2):

In running the test case and stepping through the code, my debugging shows the following substitutions...

```
transformPoint(RectF source, RectF destination, PointF point) {
    return new Point (
        (int) (((( 799 - 0 ) / 800 ) * 310 ) + 9 )),
        (int) (((( 799 - 0 ) / 800 ) * 190 ) + 9 ))
    );
}
```

The first half of the equation returns `318.6125`. The second half of the equation returns `198.7625`.

You need to either

1. modify the equation so that the `int` transformation truncates to the
   desired value (such as `+ 1` at the end)
2. round up before conversion to `int`
3. live with the result

And as Mathew noted, multiple translations in a row distort and magnify the problem, much like averaging averages.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Reenactor, you need to round points before conversion to int:

```
private Point transformPoint(RectF source, RectF destination, PointF point) {
   final int ptx = Math.round((((point.X - source.X) / source.Width) * destination.Width + destination.X));
   final int pty = Math.round((((point.Y - source.Y) / source.Height) * destination.Height + destination.Y));
   return new Point(ptx, pty);    
}
```

Comment: I think it is a little more complicated than that, as sometimes the required output needs me to Round Down, and sometimes it requires me to Round Up.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are converting the interim results after each translation to integer points?

Remember, `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point` stores `x` and `y` as `int`, so any fractions in your calculations are *dropped*.

That is:

1) First translation:

```
x1 = ((799 - 0) / 800) * 301 + 9 = 309.62375
y1 = ((799 - 0) / 800) * 181 + 9 = 189.77375
```

If you were storing those in a `Point` object before going into the next translation, they would be truncated to (309, 189) and you would get

2) Second translation

```
x2 = ((309 - 9) / 301) * 320 + 0 = 318.93...
y2 = ((189 - 9) / 181) * 200 + 0 = 198.89...
```

Which would, in turn, be truncated to (318, 198).

Comment: I definitely think it is a rounding problem.  I'm not exactly sure where and how to fix.  I've simplified the question now though

Comment: How is the 2nd translation (back to the original size) happening in your code?  I don't see the bug it what you posted, so I'm guessing that is where the problem is.  That is, that you are translating your (799,799) point to your (9,9,310,190) coordinate system, then storing the result of that as a `Point` instead of a `PointF` and translating it to your (0,0,320,200) coordinate system.  That would be the error.

Comment: I've updated my question now.  Basically it is one translation from 0, 0, 800, 800 to 9, 9, 310, 190

Comment: ... and do you not get (309, 189)?  You didn't update your expected and actual results.

Comment: I did - I get  318, 198, instead of 319, 199

Comment: Ah, I see.  310 is the width of the rectangle, not it's boundary.  In that case, you've got a simple rounding problem.  Your formulate returns 318.62375 for 'x'.  When Java puts that into an `int`, in drops, the fractional part.  It does not round it.  Surround the expressions with `Math.round()` before passing them to the `Point` constructor.

Comment: Its strange, for some test cases I need to Round Up to get the correct, and sometimes I need to round Up.  I am missing something like a scaling factor or something.